# Conversion error in c# throwing exception input string was in invalid format

Tags: c#

I am facing problem while converting string to decimal. My C# code is reading the following data from an exel file and throwing me the following error

> Input string was not in the correct format "-1.7999999999999999E-2".

I can't see this value in my excel value.

Example data

```
-1.70152
9.335628333
-150.0145233
39.159625
```

**The c# code**

```
TestModel.lat = Convert.ToDecimal(c.CellValue.Text);
```

Is my conversion correct. I am loosing out any values during the conversion. Whats the best datataype to convert to inorder to retain the original value as it is?

Comment: Note that when you're including example data, it helps to include an example which will fail....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach must be:

```
TestModel.lat = Decimal.Parse(c.CellValue.Text, NumberStyles.Float);
```

Even better you should use `Decimal.TryParse` and you should specify `InvariantCulture`

```
decimal d = 0;
Decimal.TryParse("1.2345E-02", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);

TestModel.lat = d;
```

Comment: @Jamiec it does in this case.

Comment: I *run* the code in Linqpad. AllowExponent throws. Float works

Comment: @Jamec your comment doesn't expect the culture to be invariant, try TryParse variant.

Answer (score -3):

1) open ur excel
2) click on any cell which have this value
3)right click on cell->format cell-> select general and click ok.it will show you your original value.do changes to all cells.
4) now try to read with this file with ur code